# Uploading to S3 but nothing appears in the Web Console

Tags: c#, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload CSV files to AWS S3. My code has no syntax errors and doesn't cause any exceptions but the CSV files do not appear in web console. I also want to organise the CSV files by date. Here's the code:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.csv*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = "WorkFolder";
            request.Key = "CSV/" + date + "/"; 
            request.FilePath = file;
            s3client.PutObject(request);
            response = s3client.PutObject(request);
        }
```

Comment: Your date variable in the code above is not initialised.  Also, what is the value of response ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq The data variable is initialised before this section of code. The type of response is PutObjectResponse. I have also had the last line of code as:
`s3client.PutObject(request);`

and still did not work for some odd reason

Comment: thank you - what is the value of the response ? Is there any error code or message ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq there are no error codes or exceptions being raised. The value of the response is not null and has some metadata of the `PutObjectRequest` but nothing that can be used.

Comment: what is the output of aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME ?

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I'm not sure what you mean or what that would do. Could you explain the reason of having that/doing that test?

Comment: I wonder if this is a display problem in the console or if the object is not created on S3.  Maybe the bucket (WorkFolder) does not exist, maybe you have incorrect permission on it.  Using the command line interface (AWS CLI - http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) would help to diagnose your problem.

Comment: @SébastienStormacq I have resolved the issue. The issue lay in the fact that I didn't provide a name for the objects that I wanted to upload in the Key. This is the code: 
`PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();`
`request.BucketName = "WorkFolder";`
`request.Key = "CSV/" + date + "/" + file;` 
`request.FilePath = s;`
`s3client.PutObject(request);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I was missing the "file name" in Key property. The correct code is below:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.BucketName = "WorkFolder"; 
request.Key = "CSV/" + date + "/" + file; // where file is the name of the file 
request.FilePath = s; 
s3client.PutObject(request);
```